# Manipulating /dev/video

Tags: video, devices

I'd like to take the video stream from `/dev/video0`, apply some effects or changes and make the result available on `/dev/video1`.

`/dev/video0` ---> Apply Effects ---> `/dev/video1`

For example, `mplayer tv:// -vo caca` will display the output of `/dev/video` in ascii art. I would like to make that available on `/dev/video1` so that I could  send that through skype instead of my default webcam feed....

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For sure. Here are two suggestions:

1. Behind the scenes CLI. Use [V4L2VD](http://v4l2vd.sourceforge.net/) to create a virtual video device such as /dev/videoVirt1 and pipe through mplayer for the effects. Even some similar examples in the [notes](http://v4l2vd.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/v4l2vd/v4l2vd/NOTES?revision=1.1.1.1&view=markup).
2. Use a fat desktop program such as [webcamstudio](https://sourceforge.net/projects/webcamstudio/) to create the pipes and do your skype/broadcast wonders - still with mplayer for the ascii effect

Good Luck!

Answer (score 6):

Here's another v4l2 loopback driver that I was able to get working with Skype.
[v4l2loopback driver](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback.git)
Then you can use Gstreamer to setup to pipeline.

```
apt-get install gstreamer-tools 

gst-launch -v v4l2src ! gstreamfiltershere ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1
```

Comment: Running your command, I get `Device '/dev/video0' is not a output device`. How can I avoid this? Please help.

Comment: does /dev/video0 exist at all on your system ? Your camera might be mapped to another device. check which video devices exist, with eg "ls -l /dev/video*" install the "cheese" application and see which device supplies the video ... It might be /dev/video10 for example