# Pipe VNC viewer output to /dev device

Tags: x11, vnc, ffmpeg

Using VNCTiger as a VNC viewer, how can I pipe/forward (correct terminology?) the output to one of the `/dev` devices like `video0`?

At the moment I use a basic `vncviewer` command to get the output, as follows:

```
$ vncviewer <ip>:5900 -passwd ~/.vnc/passwd
```

**Purpose:** To stream VNC output to Android Emulator camera input.

---

**Prior research**: [Using desktop as fake webcam on linux](https://superuser.com/q/411897), [Manipulating /dev/video](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5452/255720)

Using the **v4l2loopback** kernel module they stream the desktop X11 output to /dev/video0 with **ffmeg**, as follows:

```
$ ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 15 -s 1280x720 -i :0.0+0,0 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

Comment: What's wrong with the ffmpeg command? Pipe your vncviwer window as /dev/video0